# createing sub matrix/dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, submatrix

Question about dataframe manipulations. not HW, although I will phrase it as a HW problem. I know there is a 3 line way of doing this but I can't seem to find it.

**Problem**
I have a dataframe **A** with 10 columns and a thousand rows, it's filled with some data. I have a 1-column matrix **B** with 1 column and a thousand rows, it's filled by 1 and 0 (TRUE or FALSE).

Goal: create a new dataframe **C** that contains only the rows in **A** that had a TRUE value in the equivalent index of matrix **C**.

**(More clarification in case its not clear)** I performed operations on **A**, stored the result (true or false) in a column dataframe (of same length of course) and now wish to extract that into its own matrix.
The size of the new matrix is sum(B) X 10 (just a logical deduction)

Thank you for reading! Your help is appreciated.

**Example**

**Dataframe A**

```
Name   State   metric1 metric2

Joe     MA      23       25
Moe     AZ      123      2971
Bo      CA      938      387
Yo      UT       1        3
```

**matrix B**

```
1
0
1
0
```

Desired Output (**dataframe C**)

```
Name   State   metric1 metric2

Joe     MA      23       25
Bo      CA      938      387
```

Comment: It is better to include reproducible example (`dput`) and expected output to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: See the following link on creating a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for your input guys. I read Sotos's advice and produced this. Is it enough? I  think it's very clear, but obviously I would think that. Please let me know if the example provided does not make things clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply

```
A <- data.frame(cbind(A=1:10,B=21:30,C=41:50))
B <- data.frame(D=rep(c(TRUE,FALSE),5))
C <- A[B$D,]
```

giving

```
> A
    A  B  C
1   1 21 41
2   2 22 42
3   3 23 43
4   4 24 44
5   5 25 45
6   6 26 46
7   7 27 47
8   8 28 48
9   9 29 49
10 10 30 50
> B
       D
1   TRUE
2  FALSE
3   TRUE
4  FALSE
5   TRUE
6  FALSE
7   TRUE
8  FALSE
9   TRUE
10 FALSE
> C
  A  B  C
1 1 21 41
3 3 23 43
5 5 25 45
7 7 27 47
9 9 29 49
```

**EDIT after OP's edit**

```
A <- data.frame(cbind(name=c("Joe",  "Moe",   "Bo" ,  "Yo"),
                      State=c("MA","AZ","CA","UT"),
                      metric1 = c(23,123,938,1),
                      metric2 = c(25,2971,387,3)))
B <- c(1,0,1,0)
C <- A[B==1,]
C
```

giving

```
> C
  name State metric1 metric2
1  Joe    MA      23      25
3   Bo    CA     938     387
```

Comment: And if you don't like the row IDs you can always reset them back to being sequential via `rownames(C) <- 1:nrow(C)`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the stuff I was looking for. Thank you for your help and time!!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# convert you dataset into a data.table
  setDT(A)

# create a dummy variable (TRUE or FALSE) using operations other columns
  A[ , logical := sum(metric1, metric1) > 50 ]

# subset the data 
  A[ logical == T]
```